# is it safe to use WebView for android app?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I try to use HTML, CSS and JS instead of Java and XML, so I have to use WebView on Android Studio.

I just afraid that with simple Reverse Engineering anybody could access my web files and APIs...

Is it possible to do that? Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: keep the Strings encrypted and decrypt that on runtime and load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although safety of your application is at stake when using WebView, but there are ways to solve those problems as well such as:

You can keep all the URL's and Hardcoded text in **String.xml** file and call the URL's from there

Also the other way is to **obfuscate** the code using **PROGUARD**. This is primarily used to prevent reverse engineering.

Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code for better understanding.

```
Also, To obfuscate code in Android studio just go to your build.gradle file 
in your Android Studio project:

Change the minifyEnabled property from false to true
```

That's the basic obfuscation.